# How to parse and index a big file in multi parts so it can consume less memory while reading a file in input-stream?

Tags: java, parsing, elasticsearch, stream, apache-tika

I am using `Tika Apache Parser` to `parse` a file and `elastic search` to index a file.

Let's suppose I have a doc file that need to be parsed. Here is the code example:

```
public String parseToPlainText() throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

    InputStream stream = ContentHandlerExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.doc");
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    try {
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
        return handler.toString();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see test.doc file has been read at the stretch and if the file size is too large then it may cause `outofmemoryerror`. I need that I could read a file in small chuck of `input-streams` and `parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);` could accept those stream chunks. I have another issue is that file can be of any type. So how could I split files in `chuck of streams` and how could `parser` accept it? 
Importantly each file should be indexed as a single file even split into chunks while indexing, at the end.

Comment: Are you aware that a great many file formats don't support being read in chunks, and you have to load the whole thing into memory to be able to get useful information out?

Comment: How big are your files? How much of the file do you have to read before you generate an ES document...varies? or each line?